# How to add vue js functions to jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am using a reusable bootstrap modal i.e same modal for edit, delete operations.

When edit or update buttons are clicked same modal will pop up and I need to append appropriate functions to the modal footer buttons according which operation it is.

My footer buttons are like,

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn actionBtn" data-dismiss="modal">
     <span id="footer_action_button" class='glyphicon'> </span>
   </button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
   </button>
 </div>
```

When edit button is clicked,

```
    $(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
        $('#footer_action_button').text(" Update");
        $('#footer_action_button').addClass('glyphicon-check');
        $('#footer_action_button').removeClass('glyphicon-trash');
        $('.actionBtn').addClass('btn-success');
        .....
        ......
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('.actionBtn').click(updateOperation);
    });
```

similarly for delete action too..

here `$('.actionBtn').click(updateOperation);` would work well normallly.

but here updateOperation is a vueJs function,

```
    methods: {
            updateOperation: function () {
            .....
            .....
        },
   }
```

I am unable to call this update operation.

When statically adding `@click="updateOperation()"`, it works fine.

```
<button class="btn actionBtn" data-dismiss="modal"
 @click="updateOperation()">            
  <span id="footer_action_button" class='glyphicon'> </span>
</button>
```

Comment: How does Vue figure into this app? Why don't you write the whole app using Vue?

Comment: I second @RoyJ . Typically the pattern is that the app is written in vuejs and then you can use jquery inside your vue components if absolutely necessary not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to quite understand your question, but here is how I've done it:

I have a Modal component:

**Modal.vue:**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" @click="close()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            {{ title }}
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="close()">Fermer</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="save()" :disabled="loading"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" v-if="loading"></i>Confirmer</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
export default {
    props: ['title','save','close','loading']
}
```

As you can see, I take a save and close method in argument of the Modal component.

Then, when I call the component from another one, I send the methods as parameters:

**Parent.vue:**

```
<modal v-show="showModal" title="Ajouter une adresse" :save="saveAddress" :close="hideModal" :loading="savingNewAddress">
    My Modal content here
</modal>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            this.showModal = false;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveAddress () {
            console.log('fired from my parent component');
        },
        hideModal () {
            this.showModal = false;
        },
        displayModal () {
            this.showModal = true;
        }
    },
    components: {
        Modal
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!