# Dynamic, reusable modal in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent application with two child components.

- Child component A (`manager-tab`) toggles a data property in the parent app by emitting an event.
- The data property is bound to a prop in child component B (`manager-modal`).
- When that data property is toggled, `manager-modal` opens.
- Clicking "Send" on `manager-modal` then is supposed to close the modal.

The problem is, the only way I've been able to have this behavior is by directly mutating the prop which is toggled by `manager-tab`'s emitted event. This causes a console warning, and that's what I would like to have resolved. The warning is:

view.app.php

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app__container">
      <div class="app__row">
        <?php foreach ($member->rms as $rm): ?>
          <manager-tab
            :name="'<?= $rm->name; ?>'"
            :position="'RM'"
            :thumbnail="'<?= $rm->headshot ?>'"
            v-on:activate-rm-modal="activateRmModal"
          ></manager-tab>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php foreach ($member->ams as $am): ?>
          <manager-tab
            :name="'<?= $am->name; ?>'"
            :position="'AM'"
            :thumbnail="'<?= $am->headshot ?>'"
            v-on:activate-am-modal="activateAmModal"
          ></manager-tab>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <manager-modal 
    :is-active="showRmModal"
    :phone="'<?= $rm->phone ?>'"
    :full-name="'<?= $rm->fullName; ?>'"
    :email="'<?= $rm->email; ?>'"
    :position="'RM'"
    :thumbnail="'<?= $rm->headshot ?>'"
  ></manager-modal>
  <manager-modal 
    :is-active="showAmModal"
    :phone="'<?= $am->phone ?>'"
    :full-name="'<?= $am->fullName; ?>'"
    :email="'<?= $am->email; ?>'"
    :position="'AM'"
    :thumbnail="'<?= $am->headshot ?>'"
  ></manager-modal>
</div>
```

view.app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ManagerTab from '../vue-components/app/Manager_Tab.vue';
import ManagerModal from '../vue-components/app/Manager_Modal.vue';

window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    ManagerTab,
    ManagerModal
  },
  data: {
    showRmModal: false,
    showAmModal: false,
  },
  methods: {
    activateRmModal: function() {
      this.showRmModal = true;
      this.showAmModal = false;
    },
    activateAmModal: function() {
      this.showAmModal = true;
      this.showRmModal = false;
    },
  },
});
```

Manager_Tab.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="manager-tab" @click="emit">
    <img :src="this.thumbnail" class="manager-tab__thumbnail" />
    <div class="manager-tab__identity">
      <h5 class="identity__position">
        {{ this.position }}
      </h5>
      <h5 class="identity__name">
        {{ this.name }}
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="manager-tab__icon">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'manager-tab',
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    props: {
      name      : '',
      phone     : '',
      fullName  : '',
      email     : '',
      position  : '',
      thumbnail : ''
    },
    methods: {
      emit: function() {
        if (this.position == "RM") {
          this.$emit('activate-rm-modal');
        } else {
          this.$emit('activate-am-modal');
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Manager_Modal.vue:

```
<template>
    <div :class="{ 'modal-open' : isActive }" class="modal in" v-show="isActive">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal__header">
                    <img class="modal__profile-pic" :src="this.thumbnail" />
                    <div class="modal__contact-name">{{ this.name }}</div>
                    <div class="modal__contact-position">{{ this.position }}</div>

                    <div class="modal__contact-row">
                        <div class="modal__contact-phone">{{ this.phone }}</div>
                        <div class="modal__contact-separator">|</div>
                        <div class="modal__contact-email">{{ this.email }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="modal__comment-block" placeholder="Send a message..." v-model="text"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal__footer">
                    <div class="modal__send-btn" @click="sendMessage()">Send</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



<script>  
  import Axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    name: 'manager-modal',
    data() {
      return {
        isModalOpen: this.isActive,
        msg: '',
        personName: '',
        personPhone: '',
        personMessage: '',
      }
    },
    props: {
        phone       : '',
        fullName    : '',
        email       : '',
        position    : '',
        thumbnail   : '',
        isActive    : false
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage: function() {
            if (this.text) {
                this.personMessage = this.text;
                this.close();
            } else {
                console.error('No message text');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
        },
    },
  }
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import '../../../../scss/utilities/_index.scss';
    .modal-open {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

I've tried to assign the value of `isActive` in Manager_Modal.vue to a data property, and use that for my mutations.

That didn't work and I think the reason that did't work is because of how `isActive` is initially passed in from the parent app.

I've tried to do essentially the same with a computed property, but that also does not work. I did this by having a snippet like the following in Manager_Modal.vue:

```
computed: {
    isModalActive: function() {
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
}
```

My final attempted solution before coming here to SO was to try emitting another event back to the parent to toggle the respective flag (`showRmModal` or `showAmModal`) but the parent won't catch the event for some reason. In vue devtools the event fired, but it would never be caught by the parent.

I know the solution to this is right in front of me but I'm just not seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/380816/

Here are some links I went through before writing a new question:

[How to add vue js functions to jquery dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464251/how-to-add-vue-js-functions-to-jquery-dynamically)

[Web Components Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757051/web-components-design-pattern)

[Vue 2 - Mutating props vue-warn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn)

[Reuse Modal with VueJS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092782/reuse-modal-with-vuejs-2) <-- this is a year old question identical to mine, but it has no answer and I don't like digging up old threads, especially when there's no solution on them.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly-since-the-value-will-be-overwritten-whenever-the-parent-component-re-renders

Comment: Vue is one way flow, then `isActive` is one prop, so it popup the warning when you are trying to modify it. one solution is uses `v-model` syntax suger like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955159/5665870)

Comment: @Sphinx while not exactly like your example, I was able to resolve it using your direction. If you'd like, go ahead and add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. This was a tough one to overcome, so thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a prop inside a child component so it updates on the parent container too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954716/updating-a-prop-inside-a-child-component-so-it-updates-on-the-parent-container-t)

Comment: Perhaps you are not catching the emitted event correctly?   Here is a forked fiddle where it is working.  http://jsfiddle.net/skribe/cpnrLzhj/5/

Comment: There it is! @skribe's solution took care of a secondary bug where manager-tab had to be clicked twice after the initial close happened. By catching the close event, it resolved the issue. Thank you both for your assistance!